# How can I recived data from Telegram WebApp keyboard button?

Tags: java, reactjs, telegram

I'm trying to send message to bot (from telegram webapp). That's successful, but I don't know how to get the message in bot.

This is my WebApp code. I want to know to get the "WebApp message sent!"

```js
onSubmitClick(e) {
        const button = window.Telegram.WebApp.MainButton;
        if (e === 0) {
            button.text = "submit";
            button.onClick(this.send);
        } else {
            button.text = "reject";
        }
        // button.text = "test";
        this.setState(() => ({
            mainButton: button
        }))
        button.enable();
        button.show();
    }

    send(){
        alert("test oncilck!");
        //i want get it ↓
        window.Telegram.WebApp.sendData("WebApp message sent!");
    }
```

How can I get send() method's string.

Comment: java & reactjs & python ? man, where's your exact problem? Please exclude unnecessary tags.

Comment: sorryy...Java & reactjs